# unable to implement slider in RoR using asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am not able to link a css and javascript file using asset pipeline. I am a newbie so help me out in places where I make very minor mistakes too. I have basically created a very basic static page and I am trying to add a slider on the page. The slider is from http://www.basic-slider.com/.
Here is the code in the home.html.erb
    `<h1>StaticPages#home</h1>
    <p>Find me in app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb</p>
    <div id="container">
    <h2>Fade Example</h2>`

```
  <!--  Outer wrapper for presentation only, this can be anything you like -->
  <div id="banner-fade">

    <!-- start Basic Jquery Slider -->
    <ul class="bjqs">
      <li><img src="banner01.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption"></li>
      <li><img src="banner02.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption"></li>
      <li><img src="banner03.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption"></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- end Basic jQuery Slider -->

  </div>
  <!-- End outer wrapper -->

  <script class="secret-source">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      $('#banner-fade').bjqs({
        height      : 320,
        width       : 620,
        responsive  : true
      });

    });
  </script>`
```

I have copied the basic files necessary for the slider to work in the assets/javascript and assets/stylesheets

Comment: Difficult to debug without more info.  Do you have `jquery` and `bjqs` javascript files included?  Check page source to see that they are included.

Comment: Ya I have checked the source of the output file. They are all included in the code.

Comment: In that case; I tried your code and it works fine.  Do you see the images? What's not working for you?

Comment: The problem seems to be that I have not restarted the server. But I am still not able to make the images visible in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your images are in `app/assets/images/` directory.  Your image source needs to be updated to include `assets/` in the path.  Had you used `image_tag('banner01.jpg')` this would have been taken care for you by rails.

```
<!--  Outer wrapper for presentation only, this can be anything you like -->
  <div id="banner-fade">

    <!-- start Basic Jquery Slider -->
    <ul class="bjqs">
      <li><img src="assets/banner01.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption"></li>
      <li><img src="assets/banner02.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption"></li>
      <li><img src="assets/banner03.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption"></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- end Basic jQuery Slider -->

  </div>
  <!-- End outer wrapper -->

  <script class="secret-source">
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      $('#banner-fade').bjqs({
        height      : 320,
        width       : 620,
        responsive  : true
      });

    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you Vinod. Can you please tell me where to use the image_tag('filname') in the above code. Instead of img src?? The above code is not working for me.

Comment: Replace the first `li` line with the following:
`<li><%= image_tag('banner01.jpg', title: 'Automatically generated caption') %></li>' 
and similarly for other two lines.